# Postgres select date on the basis of interval array

Tags: postgresql, date, intervals

I required a custom solution to a problem in which users can choose a number of different intervals for data comparisons.

Example:

```
CURRENT_DATE - interval '1 day'
CURRENT_DATE - interval '4 day'
CURRENT_DATE - interval '7 day'
```

AND so on

So I am looking for a solution in which I can pass the array of integers in intervals like

```
select CURRENT_DATE - interval '1day' * any(ARRAY[1,4,7])
```

But it is not possible because

> op ANY/ALL (array) requires an operator to yield boolean

Comment: Side note: `SELECT CURRENT_DATE - 1` would do ;)

Comment: If the user specifies 1,4,7 do you want 3 rows returned with three different dates? How exactly do you want to use those values?

Comment: yes, you are right. The number of rows will equal to the length of the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demos:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=057648085114023b20e7a06dbb7915a6)

You can use `unnest()` to extract the array elements into one record per element and then return the `CURRENT_DATE` minus each of these elements:

```
SELECT
    CURRENT_DATE - array_element
FROM unnest(ARRAY[1,4,7]) as array_element
```

Naturally, you can put the `unnest()` into the `SELECT` list:

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE - unnest(ARRAY[1,4,7])
```

**Edit:**

If you need another date range than days you can use intervals for that:

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE - unnest(ARRAY[1,4,7]) * interval '1 week'
```

Comment: If we want to use the week array in place of the date array?
Can you please suggest that too?
select CURRENT_DATE - interval '1week' * any(ARRAY[1,4,7])